How do I get my script to ignore a blank cell instead of stopping the process?
TLDR; how do I skip empty cells instead of stopping?
I have a spreadsheet set up to create events in my calendar for a variety of tasks, and it works as expected unless a column is blank.
enter image description here
How can The second row worked fine. I had 5 events in my calendar as required. For line 1 I only need to add 3 tasks for that project to my calendar but the moment it gets to a blank, it stops completely and adds nothing further.
​
function tasksfunction() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Task Tracker");
var tasktracker= spreadsheet.getRange("A2:M2").getValues();
CalendarApp.getCalendarById('XXXX.calendarurl').createAllDayEvent('plain text: '+tasktracker[0][0],
    tasktracker[0][6]    
);
The above is repeated for each column.
}

​It works PERFECTLY for me if there is a date in each column. But I don't always need to do all 5 tasks for that project. Help!

How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?

Is it just column A you want to check if it is blank, or any cell?

You should use a JavaScript if statement with an expression that returns truthy or falsy.
You might use
if( tasktracker[0][6] ) CalendarApp.getCalendarById('XXXX.calendarurl').createAllDayEvent('plain text: '+tasktracker[0][0],
    tasktracker[0][6]    
);

if tasktracker[0][6] is truthy, then CalendarApp.getCalendarById('XXXX.calendarurl').createAllDayEvent('plain text: '+tasktracker[0][0], tasktracker[0][6]     ); will be executed; otherwise, it will be skipped.
SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() will return "" (empty string) for every cell that is blank. An empty string is falsy, and any other string value is truthy.
Related

In javascript, is an empty string always false as a boolean?

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

